# What are U-type statistics?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

In an article, I recently came across the mention of first and second order U-type statistics  without further detail.

Does anyone know what U-type statistics are?
References will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean in [this sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U-statistic)?

Comment: Huber has found the Wikipedia description of U-statistics that come up in nonparametric statistics and were original found by Hoeffding.  That is what I assumed you meant also when I saw the question.  I don't think the term U-type is common though.

Comment: It looks like it. Any hint at what first and second order could be?

Comment: Probably averages over functions taking one argument vs. averages over all pairs for functions taking two arguments. A. van der Vaart's *Asymptotic Statistics* has a chapter that provides a lovely introduction to this topic.

Comment: @cardinal yes that would make sense in the context. I will look it up. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments and the answer I got that "U-type statistics" is jargon for "U-statistics".

Here are a couple of elements taken from the reference provided by @cardinal, and in the previous answer. A U-statistics of **degree** or **order** $r$ is based on a permutation symmetric kernel function $h$ of arity $r$

$$ h(x_1, ..., x_r): \mathbb{X}^r \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, $$

and is the average of that function taken over all possible subsets of observations from the sample. More formally

$$ U = \frac{1}{\left( \array{n\\r} \right)} \sum_{\Pi_r(n)}h(x_{\pi_1}, ..., x_{\pi_r}), $$

where the sum is taken over $\Pi_r$, the set of all unordered subsets chosen from $\{1, ..., n\}$. The interest of U-statistics is that they are asymptotically Gaussian provided $E \{ h^2(X_1, ..., X_r) \} < \infty$.

**Example 1:** The sample mean is a first order U-statistics with $h(x) = x$.

**Example 2:** The signed rank statistic is a second order U-statistics with $h(x_1, x_2) = 1_{\mathbb{R}^+}(x_1+x_2)$ (the function that is equal to $1$ if $x_1 + x_2 > 0$, and $0$ otherwise).

$$ U = \frac{1}{\left( \array{n\\2} \right)} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^n 1_{\mathbb{R}^+}(x_i+x_i) $$

is the sum of pairs $(x_i, x_j)$ from the sample with positive sum $x_i+x_j > 0$ and can be used as test statistic for investigating whether the distribution of the observations is located at 0.

**Example 3:** The unit definition space $\mathbb{X}$ of $h$ need not be real. Kendall's $\tau$ statistics is a second order U-statistics with $\frac{1}{2} h((x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2)) = 1_{\mathbb{R}^+}((y_2-y_1)(x_2-x_1)) - 1$.

$$ \tau = \frac{2}{\left( \array{n\\2} \right)} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^n 1_{\mathbb{R}^+}((y_2-y_1)(x_2-x_1)) - 1 $$

is a measure of dependence between $X$ and $Y$ and counts the number of concordant pairs $(x_i, y_i)$ and $(x_j, y_j)$ in the observations.

Answer (score 2):

We have established that U-statistics are what the OP is looking for.  I will address his second question about orer of U-statistics.  The theory of U-statistics can be found in many books on nonparametrics and I am sure also in the various statistical encyclopedias. Here is a nice article by Tom Ferguson that summarizes the theory.  I think it is actually a class tutorial on it.  Here is what he says about order.  The rest you can find in the paper

> **5. Degeneracy**. When using U-statistics for testing hypotheses, it occasionally
>   happens that at the null hypothesis, the asymptotic distribution has variance zero. This
>   is a degenerate case, and we cannot use Theorem 2 to find approximate cutoff points. The
>   general definition of degeneracy for a U-statistic of order $m$ and variances, $\sigma_1^2 \leq \sigma_2^2 \leq ... \leq \sigma_m^2$ given by (19) is as follows.
>   Definition 3. We say that a U-statistic has a degeneracy of order $k$ if $\sigma_1^2 = · · · = \sigma_k^2 = 0$
>   and $\sigma^2_{k+1} > 0$.

http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tom/Stat200C/Ustat.pdf

Comment: @gui11aume Thanks for the nice editing job.  I just fixed one thing (an extra 1 at the end after k+1).

Comment: @gu11aume.  Do you know Tom Ferguson?  He was a UCLA professor way back in the late 1970s when I was a graduate student.  At Stanford would used his book in our graduate math stat course.  It was a really good text and I think he writes very well.